# Inject Angular service to controller only if it needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I try implement lazy loading of angular services, controllers, directives, filters, I found way to do something similar using RequireJS. But I cant`t found how to load service into controller dynamically only when it is needed.

My controller:

```
require(["app"], function (app) {

  app.controller('dialogsCtrl',function($scope,dialogsSer){
    $scope.tooltip = function(){
      dialogsSer.tooltip(); // work ok
    }
...
```

I want to implement something like (also to still possibility inject service as angular inline way):

```
require(["app"], function (app) {

  app.controller('dialogsCtrl',function($scope){ 
    $scope.tooltip = function(){
      // load service only if tooltip function is called
      require(["dialogsSer"], function (dialogsSer){
         dialogsSer.tooltip();  
      );
    }
...
```

require config:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: ...,    
paths: {
    ....
    'dialogService':'resources/web/app/services/dialogsSer',
     ...
deps: ['app']
});
```

Dialogs servise:

```
require(["app","directives"], function (app) {

  app.service('dialogsSer', function($http,$uibModal){

  var ds = {};
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found angular $injector method for insert service on run time.

```
require(['dialogService','userSer'],function(){
     if(!$rootScope.userSer)$rootScope.userSer = $injector.get("userSer");
     if(!$rootScope.dialogsSer)$rootScope.dialogsSer = $injector.get("dialogsSer");
     $scope.$apply(); 
});
```